# requestDispatcher.forward() returns blank webpage

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Genuinely Stumped I'm new to Trying to Develop in java and I'm struggling with creating a user login page.

I want to check if the user has a session and has a key available that I've set at authentication if not I want them to be forwarded to the **loginPage.jsp**

The code that I've provided works when I don't use the following mapping for my servlet.

```
 <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> -- This works by itself only works on paths not .jsp files
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> -- if i include this i only get blank webpages
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**web.xml**

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>Project1</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ControlServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> //Works when by itself 
   <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern> //breaks when i enabled this 
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Control Servlet.java**

```java
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControlServlet
 */

public class ControlServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ControlServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            // Not created yet. Now do so yourself.
            session = request.getSession();
        } else {
            // Already created.
        }

        //Check if User is Logged in

         String pathInfo = (request.getPathInfo() != null) ? request.getPathInfo() : request.getServletPath();
            System.err.println("check1");
             System.err.println(session.getAttribute("name") == null);
             System.err.println("check2");
             System.err.println(!"/loginPage.jsp".equals(pathInfo));         
         System.err.println(pathInfo);


         if (session.getAttribute("name") == null && !"/loginPage.jsp".equals(pathInfo))
         {   
             RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/loginPage.jsp");
             requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
             //response.sendRedirect("loginPage.jsp");
             System.err.println("did this ever happen?");

         }else {

         }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        doGet(request, response);
    }

}
```

Comment: why you are using two url patterns for same servlet?

Comment: do you mean url-pattern in the web-xml file? according to the documentation I've read this is a valid approach if not i'm open to suggestion. To directly answer your question when using just / as a filter it only works on paths. I wish to also include any .jsp file to be sent to this servlet as well.

Comment: It is because you have mapped every request with .jsp extension to the same servlet. When you forward the request it will again forwarded to same servlet instead of jsp.

Comment: @VikramSingh What would you suggest as a better approach so I can prevent people from visiting these .jsp pages without having an active session.  I definitely see what you're talking about but I Just made the assumption that once it's forwarded it once it would just loaded normally like when i'm checking for /

Comment: Add filter in web.xml file to prevent user form visiting without login.

Comment: @VikramSingh Thank you.. this put me on the right path. I like this better.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why the _eclipse_ tag on your question? How is it related to Eclipse IDE?

Comment: @Abra Valid Point I've Removed The Tag..